# How to put if condition inside php string properly

Tags: php, html

I have following code to print some data,

```
$html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Event</th><th>Tag</th><th>Time</th></tr>"

    .if(count($result->http_response_body->items) > 0) {
        foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $key) {.
             "<tr>
             <td>". $key->recipient . "</td>
             <td>". $key->event . "</td>
            <td>" . @$key->tags[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . date("r", $key->timestamp) . "</td>
            </tr>"
        .}

        //fetchLogs($result);
    }. 
     "</table>";

    echo $html;
```

When I execute code it gives syntax error, unexpected 'if' condition. How to insert this if condition and other variables inside this table string. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a lot of syntax errors

```
$html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Event</th><th>Tag</th>    <th>Time</th></tr>";

if ( count( $result->http_response_body->items ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $result->http_response_body->items as $key ) {
        $html .= "<tr>
             <td>" . $key->recipient . "</td>
             <td>" . $key->event . "</td>
            <td>" . @$key->tags[ 0 ] . "</td>
            <td>" . date( "r", $key->timestamp ) . "</td>
        </tr>";
    }

    //fetchLogs($result);
}
$html .= "</table>";

echo $html;
```

also, dont supress errors (`@$key->tags[0]`).  Do a proper check with `isset` first. Or if you are on php7 you can use the null coalesce operator like `$key->tag[0] ?? 'something else'`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Event</th><th>Tag</th><th>Time</th></tr>" ;

    if(count($result->http_response_body->items) > 0) {
        foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $key) {
          $html.=   "<tr>
             <td>". $key->recipient . "</td>
             <td>". $key->event . "</td>
            <td>" . @$key->tags[0] . "</td>
            <td>" . date("r", $key->timestamp) . "</td>
            </tr>";
        }

        //fetchLogs($result);
    } 
     $html.="</table>";

    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly PHP statements close with `;` that is semi-colon.

So, your first statement needs to be corrected as:

```
<?php
$html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Event</th><th>Tag</th><th>Time</th></tr>";
if (count($result->http_response_body->items) >0) { // Removed dot
  foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $key) { // Removed dot
    $html .= "<tr><td>" .$key->recipient ."</td>
      <td>" .$key->event ."</td>
      <td>" .@$key->tags[0] ."</td>
      <td>" .date("r", $key->timestamp) ."</td></tr>";
  } // Removed Dot.
// fetchLogs($result);
}
$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the trick is quite simple, you just have to understand string concatination, and once you've mastered that you can compose complex strings like this one.

```
$html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Event</th><th>Tag</th><th>Time</th></tr>";

    if(count($result->http_response_body->items) > 0) {
        foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $key) {
            $html."<tr>
             <td>". $key->recipient . "</td>
             <td>". $key->event . "</td>
             <td>" . @$key->tags[0] . "</td>
             <td>" . date("r", $key->timestamp) . "</td>
           </tr>";
        }

    }

   $html."</table>";

   echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are syntax errors in the code.You can use this

```
    $html = "<table><tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Event</th><th>Tag</th>    <th>Time</th></tr>";

    if ( count( $result->http_response_body->items ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $result->http_response_body->items as $key ) {
            $html .= "<tr>
                 <td>" . $key->recipient . "</td>
                 <td>" . $key->event . "</td>
                <td>" . @$key->tags[ 0 ] . "</td>
                <td>" . date( "r", $key->timestamp ) . "</td>
            </tr>";
        }


    }
    $html .= "</table>";

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

RAther than using string concatenation which can have performance penalties with large strings my personal preference is to use an array into which items are added - implode at the end to output to screen.

```
<?php

    $html=array();
    $html[]="
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Event</th>
            <th>Tag</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>";

    if ( count( $result->http_response_body->items ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $result->http_response_body->items as $key ) {
            $html[]= "
            <tr>
                <td>{$key->recipient}</td>
                <td>{$key->event}</td>
                <td>{@$key->tags[ 0 ]}</td>
                <td>" . date( "r", $key->timestamp ) . "</td>
            </tr>";
        }
    }

    $html[]= "</table>";

    echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html);
    unset( $html );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Email Address</th>
      <th>Event</th>
      <th>Tag</th>
      <th>Time</th>
   </tr>
   <?php if(count($result->http_response_body->items) > 0) : ?>
       <?php foreach ($result->http_response_body->items as $key):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $key->recipient; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key->event?; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo @$key->tags[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("r", $key->timestamp); ?></td>
            </tr>
       <?php endforeach;?>
   <?php endif;?>
</table>
```